# join table with case statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, switch-statement

I have little bit problem about query mysql.
so I have 3 tables.

orders table

| id | name_item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | harry potter | 2000 |
| 2 | dragon ball | 3000 |

users table

| id | name | referal_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | joe | 123 |
| 2 | dani | 567 |

refferals table

| id | model_type | model_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | model\order | 1 |
| 2 | model\user | 2 |
| 3 | model\user | 2 |

3 those table I want to join so I can identify which user has more contribute.

so expected result like this below.

| users.name | users.refereal_code | refferals.model_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| joe | 123 | model\order |
| dani | 567 | model\user |
| dani | 567 | model\user |

I have tried to query like this

```
select u.name, u.referal_code, r.model_type from refferal r join orders o on r.model_id = case
when r.model_type = 'model\order' then o.id
end
join users u on u.id = case
when r.model_type = 'model\user' then r.model_id
end
```

but the result show nothing.

please help me

thank you, I appreciate

Comment: Can you explain more around your goal of: _so I can identify which user has more contribute_

Comment: @GRIV every user has referal code. Referal code can use for register new user or can use for order. So i want to identify which code referal has more use for register or order. Sorry about my english

Comment: No worries. Can you add some more sample data to make this clear? Maybe some added scenarios? Because right now, a simple JOIN can achieve your expected output but I don't think that's what you want.